# Either or case in Python and Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a small module that gets the lemma of a word and its plural form. It then searches through sentences looking for a sentence that contains both words (singular or plural) in either order. I have it working but I was wondering if there is a **more elegant** way to build this expression.

Note: Python2

```
words = ((cell,), (wolf,wolves))
string1 = "(?:"+"|".join(words[0])+")"
string2 = "(?:"+"|".join(words[1])+")"
pat = ".+".join((string1, string2)) +"|"+ ".+".join((string2, string1))
# Pat output: "(?:cell).+(?:wolf|wolves)|(?:wolf|wolves).+(?:cell)"
```

Then the search:

```
pat = re.compile(pat)
for sentence in sentences:
    if len(pat.findall(sentence)) != 0:
        print sentence+'\n'
```

Alternatively, would this be a good solution?

```
words = ((cell,), (wolf,wolves))
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    if any(word in sentence for word in words[0]) and any(word in sentence for word in words[1]):
        print sentence
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `findall` with a pattern like `(cell)|(wolf|wolves)` and check if every group was matched:

```
words = (("cell",), ("wolf","wolves"))
pat = "|".join(("({0})".format("|".join(forms)) for forms in words))
regex = re.compile(pat)
for sentence in sentences:
    matches = regex.findall(sentence)
    if all(any(groupmatches) for groupmatches in zip(*matches)):
        print sentence
```

Comment: A step further than me. Seems good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you will find this way of writing more easy to read:

```
words = (('cell',), ('wolf','wolves'))

string1 = "|".join(words[0]).join(('(?:',')'))
print string1

string2 = "|".join(words[1]).join(('(?:',')'))
print string2

pat = "|".join((
                ".+".join((string1, string2)) ,
                ".+".join((string2, string1))
                ))
print pat
```

My advice is also to use `'.+?'` instead of just `'.+'`. It will spare time to the regex motor when it will run through the analysed string: it will stop as soon as it will encouters the following unary pattern.

Another adavantage is that it can be easily extended when there are several couples noun/plural.

Comment: Silly question but isn't ".+?" the same thing as ".*" ?

Comment: @Josay No. See in this link : (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) ``.+`` is greedy, ``.+?`` is ungreedy. It means that in case of ``'..cell....wolf.......'`` analysed, the regex motor of pattern ``(?:cell).+(?:wolf|wolves)``  will match **cell** and then ``.+`` will match all the subsequent characters, dots and **wolf** comprised, until the end of the string; there it will realize that it can't match ``(?:wolf|wolves)`` with anything else. So it will move backward and to search again in order to find such a pattern.

Comment: Then pattern ``(?:cell).+(wolf\d|wolves)`` will match ``'wolf2'`` in ``',,cell,,wolf1,,,wolf2,,,'`` while ``(?:cell).+?(wolf\d|wolves)`` will match ``'wolf1'``